# Combining info from two API feeds into single array

Tags: php, arrays, google-calendar-api

currently I'm working with two API calendar feeds that display a list of the events associated with them. I have both feeds information being displayed on the site, however, I would like to combine these feeds so their list of events is integrated together seamlessly. All of the API info is already stored in arrays containing information in the following format:

```
[email] => placeholder@gmail.com
```

Any ideas on how to combine the two into a single array?
I'm using PHP by the way.

Hey everyone, thanks for all of the quick responses! I guess I should clarify a bit...
One feed is pulling in an array with different array keys than the google array. So the first feed has a key of:
[LOCATION_NAME] => House

While the second one has a key of 
[location] => Apartment

How could I alter this so that the keys are the same and I can simply merge the arrays? Thanks everyone!

Comment: show your code...array formate

Comment: `array_push()`..for pushing array. `array_merge()` for merging two arrays

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your output should be like this

```
<?php
   $array1 = array();
   $array2 = array( "location" => "Apartment");
   $result = array_push($array1, array( "location" => "Apartment","LOCATION_NAME" => "House"));
   var_dump($array1);
?>
```

output

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'location' => string 'Apartment' (length=9)
      'LOCATION_NAME' => string 'House' (length=5)
```

both have same key

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to combine ([merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)) two arrays:

```
<?php
   $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
   $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
   $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
   print_r($result);
?>
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: Yes, the source is php.net, but it answered his question.